# sign bitcoin transaction offline

Tags: bitcoin, sign, blockchain, bitcoind

how to sign this transaction offline?

bitcoins received from:

https://www.blocktrail.com/tBTC/tx/6971035c95e8997e55dfe18c2940edeb4137b3e41b33af478b9b5512068c5164

```
TXID= 6971035c95e8997e55dfe18c2940edeb4137b3e41b33af478b9b5512068c5164
```

amount: 10
received to address: mgnKCYotzvX9gK36vZEd86WJMN8bdtB1sF

```
createrawtransaction '[{"txid":"6971035c95e8997e55dfe18c2940edeb4137b3e41b33af478b9b5512068c5164","vout":1}]' '{"2N4ofFPCXk7NMRduBc59bPnM2CksXdk9964":0.1}'
```

returns:

```
010000000164518c0612559b8b47af331be4b33741ebed40298ce1df557e99e8955c0371690100000000ffffffff01809698000000000017a9147ecbc7d9cbb793ffb9a2905876c49f19cef8f75a8700000000
```

decode it (to get vout hex)

```
decoderawtransaction 010000000164518c0612559b8b47af331be4b33741ebed40298ce1df557e99e8955c0371690100000000ffffffff01809698000000000017a9147ecbc7d9cbb793ffb9a2905876c49f19cef8f75a8700000000
```

returns:

```
{
    "txid" : "04c557d38051d1450ff501520b1d7895c127543b435ee34e8bb76da4139f2e4b",
     "version" : 1,
     "locktime" : 0,
     "vin" : [
         {
             "txid" : "6971035c95e8997e55dfe18c2940edeb4137b3e41b33af478b9b5512068c5164",
             "vout" : 1,
             "scriptSig" : {
                 "asm" : "",
                 "hex" : ""
             },
             "sequence" : 4294967295
         }
     ],
     "vout" : [
         {
             "value" : 0.10000000,
             "n" : 0,
             "scriptPubKey" : {
                 "asm" : "OP_HASH160 7ecbc7d9cbb793ffb9a2905876c49f19cef8f75a OP_EQUAL",
                 "hex" : "a9147ecbc7d9cbb793ffb9a2905876c49f19cef8f75a87",
                 "reqSigs" : 1,
                 "type" : "scripthash",
                 "addresses" : [
                     "2N4ofFPCXk7NMRduBc59bPnM2CksXdk9964"
                 ]
             }
         }
     ]
  }
```

get private key of address

```
dumpprivkey mgnKCYotzvX9gK36vZEd86WJMN8bdtB1sF
```

returns:

```
XXX
```

sign it:

```
signrawtransaction "010000000164518c0612559b8b47af331be4b33741ebed40298ce1df557e99e8955c0371 690100000000ffffffff01809698000000000017a9147ecbc7d9cbb793ffb9a2905876c49f19cef8f75a8700000000" "[{\"txid\":\"6971035c95e8997e55dfe18c2940edeb4137b3e41b33af478b9b5512068c5164\",\"vout\":1,\"scriptPubKey\":\"a9147ecbc7d9cbb793ffb9a2905876c49f19cef8f75a87\", ,\"redeemScript\":\""]" "ALL"
```

Running this returns all the time just an input on my server. When I hit enter nothing happens:
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a space in your raw transaction between `55c0371 6901000`. Remove it. Also, it should be as simple as that:

```
signrawtransaction 010000000164518c0612559b8b47af331be4b33741ebed40298ce1df557e99e8955c0371690100000000ffffffff01809698000000000017a9147ecbc7d9cbb793ffb9a2905876c49f19cef8f75a8700000000
```

You should not need the other arguments as it uses whatever is available. This [question is a good reference](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/a/12760/6441).

Answer (score -1):

You are not include required parameter: `amount` in sign transaction
try this example and change `value_from_transaction` to value from your transaction) from listunspent:

```
signrawtransaction "010000000164518c0612559b8b47af331be4b33741ebed40298ce1df557e99e8955c0371
690100000000ffffffff01809698000000000017a9147ecbc7d9cbb793ffb9a2905876c49f19cef8f75a8700000000"
 "[{\"txid\":\"6971035c95e8997e55dfe18c2940edeb4137b3e41b33af478b9b5512068c5164\",\"vout\":1,\"scriptPubKey\":\"a9147ecbc7d9cbb793ffb9a2905876c49f19cef8f75a87\",
 \"value\": value_from_transaction]"
```

Comment: Code only answers are discouraged here. Please click on the edit button and add a brief summary of what your code does or why it works.